# What lists/structs should I build? logical question for a program for students attending to courses

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

We got an assignment in school and if there is a possibility to help me I will be so glad.

The mission is to build a program that handles courses and student registration to it.

The courses:

- each course has a name
- ID

there are up to 10 courses.

The students:

- each student has an ID
- each student has a name
- courses and grades of them.

So the options of the program are:

- receive a new course.
- update the name of a course.
- add a new student
- add a new course to the student with a grade.
- update the grade of a specific course in a student.
- the average grade of a specific course
- all students attending a course.

my idea:
I thought of making a course struct with the following:
[image: STRUCT course]

in the main, I will make an array of COURSES with 10 places

students:
[image: student]
a list of students with 10 courses for each

Now the problems I'm facing:

1. if I change the name of one course I need to make a loop to change for each student that's attends to it but it's so complicated.
2. for the average grade of a course I need to go over all students which seems so dumb to me.

I'm not looking for a code solution, only a logical help to understand,
which lists should I do? student's one? or courses one? or both? or maybe another one for grades as well?
just looking to understand how to face this issue

Comment: "but it's so complicated".  The job of the programmer is to simplify the task so that it is not complicated.  There should only be one location in which the course name is stored, and it will only need to be updated there.  Each student in the course should hold a reference (a pointer) to that course.

Comment: Thank you fro the response! could you advice me where should I keep the grades of each student for each course?

Comment: It really depends on what type of queries you'll be making.  For a toy problem, it's probably sufficient to record the grade in the student structure.  For a real problem, you'd probably want to build a relational database.

Comment: i will try this question after 3 days. Seems like an interesting question.

Comment: i think its more of a database problem.

Comment: Posting code as text is more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not looking for a code solution, only a logical help to understand, ...

---

> "if I change the name of one course I need to make a loop to change for each student thats attends to it but it's so complicated."

That is due to weak design.  Let us make a new type

```
typedef struct {
  COURSE *c;
  int grade;
  bool valid;
} cgv;
```

... and remove `.grade`, `.valid` from `COURSE`.

Consider a type `cgv courses[10];` improves things. By having a pointer to the COURSE, then only one change needed.

> for the average grade of a course I need to go over all students wich seems so dumb to me.

If the `COURSE` had a list of students in it  (similar to `STUDENT` has a list of `COURSE`s but done with pointers as answered above), then only those students taking the course needs to be averaged.

---

Consider there are two sets of data: courses, students.  Each set has references to the other.

For me, I would not embed the `.next` member in `STUDENT`, but create generic linked-list with each node having 2 pointers: data, next.

Then linked-lists could be used as 1) List of students, 2) List of courses 3) as a student member: list of courses taken 4) as a course member, list of students in the course.

---